# How to convert .bin-files to .iso-files fast?

Tags: performance, iso, conversion

I try to convert a `.bin` CD image file (with no `.cue`-file) of less than 800 MB with [`iat`](http://portsmon.freebsd.org/portoverview.py?category=sysutils&portname=iat) (Iso9660 Analyzer Tool v0.1.7) to an `.iso`-file on FreeBSD. With an AMD FX-8370 after 30 minutes `iat` still has not finished yet (`iat` uses one core with nearly 100% load).

Is this normal? Is there any way to make `iat` work faster? Or what other better alternative is there to convert `.bin`-files into `.iso`-files?

I have multiple images to convert and I've never seen such a bad performance when handling large files. Decompression of an encrypted 20 GB archive takes less time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this issue happen when bin/raw image is not a ISO/UDF image but Audio Image

In according with [man page](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/33588567/numer/1/nazwa/iat) of iat, program doesn't support  zlib images or audio